How to make ModalBottomSheet as wrapContentHeight Jetpack compose
How to make ModalBottomSheet to wrapContentHeight?
I'm using Material 3.
My ModalBottomSheet have only two states - half of the screen or full screen.
But I have LazyColumn little higher then half of screen.
How to make ModalBottomSheet as wrapContentHeight?
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = false)
sheetState.partialExpand()
ModalBottomSheet(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentHeight(),sheetState = sheetState){
    LazyColumn(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(1.dp)) {
    }
}

